# best api for XML to java objects

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb

I do transform my XML file into java objects, after some researche i find many API : JAXB, JAXB2, Casto, Xtream, Simpl, XMLBeans...

I would like to know the best one to use for this manner in the context of spring boot, micro-services. reliable, fast, simple. can you give an some exemple.

thank to all.

Comment: The reason StackOverflow discourages this kind of question is that no-one can tell you which option is "best" for you based on a two-sentence statement of your requirements. If you want advice on this, employ a consultant who will go to great lengths to find out about your business drivers, technology constraints, etc etc, and will charge you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience with Xsteam is the best choice not only for XML but for JSON with or without annotations.

Other API is highly dependented on Annotations.

So if you have dynamic class object then go for Xstream.

Comment: with Xstrem i have this error : `Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable.
2019-10-13 20:26:27.365 ERROR 6640 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: records] with root cause

com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: records`

Comment: Can you post the code .. have you used the required dependency of Xstream in your classpath ?